# How to use RouteBoxer.java in my Android project. How to pass the lat long for source and destination

Tags: android, routeboxer

RouteBoxer routeBoxer = new RouteBoxer();

routeBoxer.box() // it needs latlng and range.  but how to pass lat lng there.  its also not working